# First downvoting of a post after a long time

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, down-votes

I just got downvoted without any comment! :-)

I know that it has been discussed a lot before and members have a split opinion on 'making comment mandatory when downvoting'. But, here I have one specific case, so I am creating a new post. I think this case has not been discussed before.

Look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900576/url-percent-encoding-in-java/18900975#18900975)

The answer was given approx 3 years back, which has attracted a downvote on 25-Aug. I understand that the answer may not be valid **now** because of many reasons and hence can attract a downvote.

Here, my point is - **'Should we make it mandatory to comment, when first downvote is made on an answer given a long time (say 12 month) ago'.**

The definition of 'long time' can be decided by consensus.

If it is a concern of 'not revealing the identity of down-voter', I believe the stackexchange developer could make the downvoting comment as 'anonymous' (and making it mandatory to comment on downvoting).

Please let me know your opinion.

**EDIT**

After seeing so much reservation on my suggestion, I have a final point to make.

I believe SO is a community driven forum and good answer will eventually find its place due to rating system. However, the answer has already been viewed 2180 times in two years and nobody found it 'eligible for downvoting'. Then all of a sudden a downvote appears - Can anyone please let me know, what should I improve in this answer?

No need to refer me towards generic FAQs on writing good post. If you have anything to say about improving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900576/url-percent-encoding-in-java/18900975#18900975) post, it is welcomed.

Comment: one of the reasons for a downvote shows up when you hover over the button *"This answer is not useful"*. it's very possible that someone came to your answer while logged in and didn't find it useful.

Comment: personally i find any sort of "force downvoter to comment" now-a-days to be a discouragement to downvote because i don't want to keep putting in the same comment every time someone just posts code and doesn't explain it [like some answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39198865/1028804). think about [this quote](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1645170/quotes?qt=qt1765050), applies to programming as well; give a dev teh codz and he'll work for a day, teach a dev the code and he'll work for a lifetime.

Comment: I'm okay with this suggestion, as long as "long time" is defined to be 150 years.

Comment: I don't think our "members have a split opinion on 'making comment mandatory when downvoting'" or if they do then that split is about 1:10 like you are seeing in the voting on your feature request.

Comment: Lots of people don't like Stack Overflow, including users who reached over 100 rep and got hostile after for example getting into question bans, rude comments, etc. Some of those might become "downvote trolls", who just randomly downvote posts, without any reason besides causing harm to Stack Overflow. For all we know, you might be a victim of such a troll. No reason can be provided, unless you expect those people to leave "I downvoted because I hate Stack Overflow". (Which is pretty silly, as it will just lead to their suspension.)

Comment: I down vote answers that might contain errors: *%3F (or numeric 36)*. That should be 63 I believe ...

Comment: Thanks @rene, I just updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that, I am glad that I could make the post better - because you cared to point the mistake via comment :) .

Answer (score 3):

> Should we make it mandatory to comment, when first downvote is made on an answer given a long time (say 12 month) ago.

Nah, such a feature would be redundant at best.

Down votes generally mean the following (from the down vote button tooltips):

> - This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful
> - This answer is not useful

If the OP wants to give more-specific feedback, regardless of whether they voted or not, they can already leave a comment. Otherwise the above reasoning can be assumed.

No point in also posting a comment to echo the tooltip. Or worse, they could just post garbage for the comment.